Can you make a car powered by 4 car air jacks? Using the mechanics of a manual pedal pottery wheel
If an air jack can pump up a car using little force, can’t an aluminum air jack spin a plastic wheel barrel car going at least 10 mph?
Each wheel will have an air jack that uses the mechanics of a manual pedal pottery wheel.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There's better ways than using an "air jack." Google for "pneumatic motor." But if you are hoping to build a practical automobile that is powered by stored compressed air, I'm afraid you may be disappointed by its range. SCUBA tanks come close to the limit of how much you would want to compress the air: I don't want to commit to exact numbers, but I think a liter of gasoline yields something on the order of ten thousand times as much useable energy as you can obtain from one fully charged, standard size SCUBA tank.

Also note: Using SCUBA tanks for energy storage, you'll be isothermally compressing and storing the air when you charge the tanks, but if you want your car to move much faster than an ant can craw, then you'll probably have to allow it to adiabatically expand to do the work of moving the car. Again, I don't want to do the numbers (too lazy), but I think that's an unhappy combination if your goal is to make efficient use of whatever energy source compresses the air.
